# asp.net c#, assign a value to a casted object anonymously (one liner challenge!)

Tags: c#, variables, casting, variable-assignment, anonymous

Ight, so i love one liners, and I've gotten pretty good as condensing all kinds of stuff. For some reason they make me happy, and they help me learn. The highlights of the life of a computer programmer!

So anyways, i need help with this one with a casted object assignment:

Here's an example of a simple property:

```
protected InterfaceType Object{
    get{ return (InterfaceType)this.Page;} // no red squigglies, works fine
    set{ (InterfaceType)this.Page = value; } // red squigglies(left hand of argument must be a variable, property or indexer)
}
```

However i could do this:

```
protected InterfaceType Object{
    get{ return (InterfaceType)this.Page;} // no red squigglies, works fine
    set{ var o = (InterfaceType)this.Page; o = value; } // works fine
}
```

If (InterfaceType)this.Page returns an object as evident by:

```
return (InterfaceType)this.Page;
```

And i can assign it to stuff:

```
var o = (InterfaceType)this.Page;
```

And assign stuff to it:

```
o = value;
```

To me, i feel like i'm creating a new unnecessary pointer to something; since the below is just a pointer to this object in itself if i can retrieve it with it:

```
(InterfaceType)this.Page
```

Comment: does set{ ((InterfaceType)this.Page) = value; } do anything for you? just off the top of my head. I looks like an extra semi-colon is throwing things off a bit too.

Comment: What type is this.Page ?

Comment: System.Web.UI.Page, it implements the interface and by casting to the page, i can access it and have other classes access the page via the interface property.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to remove extra semi-colon after this.page and remove type casting.

*Change*

```
set{ (InterfaceType)this.Page; = value; }
```

*To*

```
set{ this.Page = value; }
```

Comment: There is no need to cast `value` on the `set`. That is already checked/done.

Comment: Casting should not be on left side of assignment operator though.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here. If `this.Page` was declared as an instance of `InterfaceType`, there'd be no casting necessary at all.

That indicates that you're trying to downcast an instance of `InterfaceType` to whatever type `Page` is in the setter. Obviously, that's not safe and your cast isn't going to work anyway. I would change it to:

```
set { this.Page = (value as WhateverTypePageIs); }
```

This means that your setter will no longer throw an Exception if the cast is invalid, it will simply set `this.Page` to `null`. If that's not desirable, you could use:

```
set { this.Page = ((WhateverTypePageIs)value); }
```

Which would still throw the Exception.

All of this, though, points to a deeper issue. If you want to have setter but store the value as a more specific type, you should make `Object` be the same type as `this.Page` so you make that restriction clear to any callers.

Answer (score -1):

You must cast the right hand side of the expression to the desired type:

```
set{ this.Page = (InterfaceType)value; }
```

However, reading your code, it is entirely possible that `Page` is defined as a lesser type in the inheritance hierarchy; in which case no cast is necessary:

```
set { this.Page = value; }
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the right hand side of the argument will already be of type "InterfaceType", and it says it cannot convert the righthand type of InterfaceType to Page type.

Comment: Again, what type is Page ?

Comment: There is no need to cast `value` on the `set`. That is already checked/done